# Can I find total payment counts based upon DATEDIFF for several kinds of installment frequencies?

Tags: sql, reporting

I am trying to see if I can count the number of payments using the DATEDIFF command in SQL.

The frequency installment types are:

Annually
Semiannually
Quarterly
Bimonthly
Monthly
Semi-monthly
Biweekly
Weekly

The installment types are used to track recurring gift payments that may or may not have an end date.  Currently, all of the constituents in the recurring payment plan do have end dates that are categorized by one of the frequency installment types.

The gift table has start payment date and end payment date so I tried to use DATEDIFF command in SSMS.  However, I am not sure whether this is the right path to take.  There is a application interphase that can generate the future payment dates under the Report function provided by the Vendor.  The backend only records the recurring payment transactions that have already happened.  I am wondering on whether the counts needs to create a calendar.  I've also thought about multiplying the recurring amount with 12 for monthly, etc.  However, when it comes to columns that indicates "start on certain day of the month" I don't think it'll work.

Can someone provide me with some tips?

I tried DATEDIFF and DATEADD, but this only covers the year, month, quarter and not other types like bimonthly, etc. The goal is to create a column that can serve as a count for the installment type.  For example, if the recurring gift is for one year, then total number of counts for monthly pay should give me a total of 12 counts.

Current table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HH2vW.png)

Desired table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5U8TO.png)

Comment: you need to show the table DDL, sample data, expected output

Comment: Look at date part.  For instance, bi-monthly can be a grouping by days that are 1 and 15.  However, like the comment above.  We need more information to give exact help!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 - Here is the link for date part.

Comment: Just edited to attempt to add the table(s).

Answer (score 0):

While this is all certainly possible, as CRAFTY DBA pointed out there are still some important missing details.

For example - while annually, semiannually, quarterly, and weekly are fairly well defined in terms of how you'd structure the DATEDIFF, others aren't. For example, biweekly could mean any two days of the week based on your current definition. We don't know what days are implied by semi monthly in your operating environment either. We also don't know whether the start or the end date is the peg for payments. In your first annual example - are the payments made annually on 11/28/2027, or on 12/29/2023?

Other details that could complicate this further are what dates are these payments eligible on - if a payment is regularly made on the 10th, and it's on a weekend, does the payment get taken on Monday and is that a level of detail that you want to capture?

Once you have definitions of dates you should be able to use the different date/time functions available to you alongside a case statement to process through all the rulesets.